# How to Display API Data in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script>
     function fetchdata() {
     $.get("http://10.10.35.138:5000/data", function (data) { //The link of this line is my API link
                $("#visitor").html('Visitor Count : ' + data.people);
                $("#time").html('Time : ' + data.time);
            });
        }
</script>
```

****HTML PART****

```html
<div class="details">
<p id="visitor">Person Count:</p>
<p id="time">Time:</p>`enter code here`
</div>
```

My API data is consist of 2 things count and time. I have mentioned two paragraphs above: I want to display count in first paragraph tag. And I want to display Time is another paragraph. I try more time but API data will not appear paragraph tags. Please help me

Comment: How are you calling `fetchdata()` method ?

Comment: The code inside fetch data works. Make sure data is returned as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to implement jquery/ajax into html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763973/trying-to-implement-jquery-ajax-into-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for making iteration in the data fetched from api provider

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
});
```

For each iteration we need to add the value to html:

```
$("#details").append('<p id="visitor"> ' + value. people  + '</p> <p id="time">' + value.time + '</p>' );

$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  $("#details").append('<p id="visitor">' + value. people + '</p> <p id="time">' + value.time + '</p>' );
});
```

final code will be:

```
<script>
     function fetchdata() {
     $.get("http://10.10.35.138:5000/data", function (data) { //The link of this line is my api link
               $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                     $("#details").append('<p id="visitor">' + value. people + '</p> <p id="time">' + value.time + '</p>' );
               });
           });
     }
</script>

****HTML PART****
<div class="details">
<p id="visitor">Person Count:</p>
<p id="time">Time:</p>`enter code here`
</div>
```

also if your api data consist just one record of value your code will be:

```
function fetchdata() {
     $.get("http://10.10.35.138:5000/data", function (data) { //The link of this line is my api link
         $("#visitor").html(data.people);
         $("#time").html(data.time);
     });
}

****HTML PART****
<div class="details">
<p id="visitor">Person Count:</p>
<p id="time">Time:</p>`enter code here`
</div>
```

Comment: <script>
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        fetchdata();
    }, 2000);


function fetchdata() {
     $.get("http://10.10.35.138:5000/data", function (data) { //The link of this line is my api link
               $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                     $(".details").append("<p id="visitor"> value. people  </p> <p id="time"> value.time  </p>" );
               });
           });
     }  
  
</script>

Comment: Sir thanks for reply but kindly suggest another way plz

Comment: var interval = setInterval(function () {
        fetchdata();
    }, 2000); // Sir this code is also include scripting part plz help me